# Unable to show data to javascript after getScript() from API contain Json block database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web

I am new to Ajax/json/jquery so I have few questions. Currently, I'm having an API like https://example/api/1.1 which contain JSON block look similar to this

```
    [{"id":"1","FirstName":"Micheal","LastName":"Kooling"},{"id":"2","FirstName":"Mike","LastName":"Kooling"}]
```

1. I tried to use XMLHttpRequest and AJAX to fetch the data but it gave me an error that I have been blocked by CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. And I have looked at a lot of article about it and nothing worked yet so if anyone can help me solve this?
2. So I tried another way using `$(function(){ $.getScript('https://example/api/1.1');});` and this time the server response the data correctly but I do not know how to show the data from the API to script?
3. Can anyone explain me why the server respone and did not get blocked when I'm using getScript() function?

Answer (score 0):

The API-Server has to be configured to accept your request. Otherwise it will block it and the client will throw the CORS error. The only way around this is to let your server request the API and then let the client make a request to your server, or to ask the owner of the server to enable CORS for your domain.

For further information look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks, I think the easiest way would be grant access from the owner server but do you know the reason why the server respone the data when I used getScript() instead?